# How do I SOSL across objects, matching all records with FIND clause?

Tags: sobject, dynamic-soql, sosl, query, dynamic-sosl

To all the expert SOSL gurus lurking out there, I thought this will be an interesting one:

I have some SObjects of different types and I want to return their `Name` values in a single query.

In advance, I *know* the IDs and the ObjectTypes of the records whose Names I wish to retrieve. It seems 'wrong' to make several SOQL queries even though there aren't too many types.

So being a good platform citizen, I'm using [Dynamic](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm) [SOSL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm) to retrieve what I need in a single query:

```
List<List<SObject>> sobjectsLists = Search.query(
    'FIND {*?*} RETURNING ' +
    'CustomOne__c (Name WHERE Id IN (\'a01000000000000AAA\')),' +
    'CustomTwo__c (Name WHERE Id IN (\'a02000000000000AAB\')),' +
    'CustomThr__c (Name WHERE Id IN (\'a03000000000000AAC\'))'
);
System.debug(sobjectsLists);
```

**But there is one problem: I must specify at least one FIND character and `{*?*}` doesn't cut it.**

> System.SearchException search term must be longer than one character: *?*

I've tried this to no avail: `{*a* OR *b* OR *c* OR *d* OR *e* OR ...}` but even if that did work, it wouldn't help in the case that some twisted cowboy puts underscore (`_`) or god forbid umlaut (`ä`).

Any guidance on how I can get the `Name` of all these records at once?

Comment: SOSL wouldn't ever work: I regularly name my accounts with non-clashing symbols, like ♥LOVE♥. I'm sure plenty of people forget that there's many languages out there, many of which don't use a-z to begin with. You couldn't possibly construct a meaningful search phrase out of that.

Comment: Could you "cache" the Names from objects you're interested in in a helper object and query that one? I'm thinking about Analytic Snapshot / simple trigger that means something can act like a view on multiple source objects.

Comment: I more stupid idea. Can you tag your records with tag name = record's name :D

Comment: the search where id in approach is very inefficient, you'd be better just running the multiple soql queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a field on your object called `Id__c`

make a workflow rule with field update that copies `Id` across to `Id__c`

```
[
    FIND 'a01000000000001 OR a02000000000002 OR a03000000000003 OR ...' RETURNING
    CustomOne__c (Name),
    CustomTwo__c (Name),
    CustomThr__c (Name)
]
```

**caveats:**

- search is case insensitive
- this work around would make use of the use of the `metadata api` to create workflow rule, field update, custom field etc

Comment: Nice idea! But I think the field will have to be marked as ext. id to be used in searches?

Comment: I gave this a go and it was searchable just by virtue of being text @eyescream - shame that ID is not!!!

Answer (score 7):

Found a way to do this in SOSL but with major caveats: the clauses in `RETURNING` are applied *after* the search, so if the result limits are reached, **the records won't be found**. (courtesy [superfell](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/144/superfell))

Trick is to satisfy the `FIND` clause with **`'* OR *'`** and use the `WHERE` clause to do the selecting:

```
[
    FIND '* OR *' RETURNING
    Account (Name WHERE Id = '0012400000DFDp0'),
    Contact (Name WHERE Id = '0032400000Ar4as'),
    Partner (Name WHERE Id = '00I2400000Ar4as'),
    Herp__c (Name WHERE Id = 'a0124000000yn22'),
    Derp__c (Name WHERE Id = 'a0224000000n3ll'),
    Doop__c (Name WHERE Id = 'a032400000001ps')
]
```

It gives the `Id` and the `Name` from any number of objects, costing a single SOSL query.

Query string can be dynamically assembled, using `Id.getSObjectType` to get the API names.

Comment: This place would be more helpful if people downvoting answers commented.

Comment: if you have large amounts of data you'll get burned by search result truncations the filter in the returning clauses are applied after the search index is processed, so if you hit the search result limits, you can not find your records.

Comment: Super insightful @superfell - tried this in an org with 229272 records and the result set is... (you guessed it) an empty list; thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5):

That's an abuse of SOSL; you're trying to hack around a critically missing piece in Apex Code: `retrieve()`. Retrieve isn't available in Apex Code (and for [goodness' sake, why NOT?!](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLtAAI)). SOQL is the only appropriate way to retrieve records by ID, for now.

Comment: Side note... I just realized I linked to my own idea, and it has never been voted on. Do people not need this feature?

Comment: Interesting to put a name to the sfdcfox via Salesforce ideas. Pleased to meet you Brian :)

Comment: He's going to delete his comment and flag yours for moderator attention in 3...2...1 ;)

Comment: My real name, and age, are on my profile. I used this moniker to associate this account with my [DeveloperForce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsProfile?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2&userId=005F0000003FXBVIA4) profile.

Comment: I think I need to add an About Me. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Answer (score 1):

If you could "promise" that each record has at least 1 related Task / Event maybe you could pull this ... stunt... by querying Event with Polymorphic SOQL enabled...

Last example in [`TYPEOF` docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) looks promising

```
SELECT 
  TYPEOF What
    WHEN Account THEN Phone, NumberOfEmployees
    WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate
    ELSE Name, Email
  END
FROM Event
```

If they'll terminate your org for system abuse don't blame me ;)

Comment: And, since we're going for workarounds, why not just call the REST API and call retrieve on up to 2,000 rows at once?

Comment: ah yes, good call @eyescream - `Activities` being the original polymorphic metadata