# SOSL working in dev org not working in sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sosl

I am attempting to search for records that contain some text and limit the search results to a group of Ids.
For simplicity, I'll remove the "search for text" part in this question.

The problematic query looks like this

```
FIND {* OR *} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING  Lead(Id, Name, Company Where Id IN ('someId')) , Contact(Id, Name, AccountId, Phone, MobilePhone, Email, MailingAddress Where Id IN('someId'))
```

In the sandbox, this query returns 0 rows no matter what if I enter a Lead's Id.. However if I split the SOSL into two parts with one for Lead and one for Contact, both can return records.

Combined : [image: combined]

Combined with contact ID : [image: combined with contactid]

Lead by itself : [image: lead by itself]

In the dev org however, the query works without a hitch even if I enter a Lead's ID.

Combined : [image: combined dev]

Lead by itself: [image: lead by itself on dev]

Is there some sort of setting that I should be looking for or is this correct behavior?

**I know that IDs are unique to each org, the IDs shown in the examples above were taken from the org that I was testing on, I am not using the same ID everywhere to test.**

Comment: IDs are unique for the org

Comment: @EricSSH : Yes I am aware, and those IDs were taken from their respective orgs

Comment: You seem to have indicated this question is already answered here: [How do I SOSL across objects, matching all records with FIND clause?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/how-do-i-sosl-across-objects-matching-all-records-with-find-clause)

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate, you should be able to agree with it and the Community user will close it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/how-do-i-sosl-across-objects-matching-all-records-with-find-clause)

> if you have large amounts of data you'll get burned by search result
>   truncations the filter in the returning clauses are applied after the
>   search index is processed, so if you hit the search result limits, you
>   can not find your records. – superfell